# Replace character in string with another character by a list of positions

Tags: python, string

How can I replace some characters in a string with another character on different positions?
For example I have the string: `string="********u"`,the list: `list=[0,2,4]` and `character = 'a'` . How can I replace `string[0]`, `string[2]`, `string[4]` with `a` ?

Answer (score 9):

You can try this:

```
s = "********u"
l ={0,2,4}
final_string = ''.join(["a" if i in l else a for i, a in enumerate(s)])
```

Output:

```
'a*a*a***u'
```

Comment: In this case, it is more efficient to use a set instead of a list. Sets has O(1) for containment checks.

Comment: @Vinny thank you for pointing that out. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a function and pass the parameter as index ,string and replace character :

```
def replace(index_list,character,string):
    string=list(string)

    for index in index_list:
        string[index]=character
    return "".join(string)
print(replace([0,2,4],'a',"********u"))
```

Output:

```
a*a*a***u
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
your_string = list("********u")
your_list = [0,2,4]

for index_number in your_list:
    your_string[index_number] = 'a'

your_output = ''.join(your_string)
print(your_output)
```